# left multiplication by invertible matrix doesn't change reduced row echelon form

Tags: matrices

How to proof that for the matrices:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
a & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$,
$X\in M_{23}(\mathbb R)$

$A(BX)$ has the same reduced row echelon form as $X$ ?

Of course I know: $A(BX) <=> (AB)X$, A is an elementary matrix and B is the product of an elementary matrix. I also know, that the reduced row echelon form is distinct. But how to show that ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
a & 1
\end{pmatrix}$,
$B_1=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B_2=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ are elemanter matrices and $B=B_1B_2$

Also reduced forms of a matrix can be obtain multipliying  that matrix by elemanter matrices.

Comment: i know but there are n elementary matrices missing to transform an arbitrary matrix X to a distinct reduced form

Comment: i know there are finite elementary matrices required to transform X to the reduced row echelon form. but i don't know how to show that the multiplication of some arbitrary elementary matrices to X transforms X to X` and X` can be transformed to the same reduced row echelon form as X

Comment: $T_1, T_2 \in M_{23}(\mathbb R)$ are matrices in reduced row echelon form. $E=E_s,E_{s-1}...E_1$ and $F=F_t,F_{t-1}....F_1$ is the product of elementary matrices so that $EX=T_1$ and $F(AB)X=T_2$. $E$, $F$ and $AB$ are invertible because they are a product of elementary matrices:

$X=E^{-1}T_1=F^{-1}(AB)^{-1}T_2 => (FABE^{-1})T_1=T_2$

But we have to show that $T_1=T_2$ !?